# How to copy the System folder in stock ROM?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, root-access, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 sm-n900, i copied the 'system' folder from the root directory to my computer, i used the **JoelDroid Lollipop Batch Deodexer** to deodex my system, now i wiped my original system folder from my device using CWM recovery. How do i push the DeoDexed system folder to my device?

I need this for installing xposed framework, it requires a deodexed rom on my device. i have already tried zipping the system with a META-INF and flashing it in CWM recovey, my device never boots to samsung logo.

Comment: do i have a bad META-INF?

Comment: I recommend you go to xda-developers and search for deodexed stock ROMs. Alternatively flash a stock ROM and copy the deodexed apks to it without deleting everything else.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/script-app-joeldroid-lollipop-batch-t2980857 sorry i forgot to mension ,i have tried this already, there is only aurora rom which is stock samsung based and it really sucks! i cant even customize it, its bloated and i cant have my own apps i get stuck in boot loops, its loaded with note 5 and s6 junk so i decided to stick with cyanogenmod

Answer (score 0):

Try any recovery FileManager like this one [Aroma File Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) and make sure you give appropriate file permissions for the system folder..!

Comment: AFM is a good thing to have. The permission part is however very hard to do, since different folders and files sometimes have varying permissions, owners and SELinux contexts. At this point I think OP should go look for a deodexed ROM instead. Still an effective answer nonetheless.